# Learning the Art of Electronics - diode clamp

Tags: diode-clamp

Working through Learning the Art of Electronics, Hayes T, I'm stuck trying to build the diode clamp in Figure 3L.7 on page 137, as below:

[image]

The text says to, "*Drive it with a sinewave from your
function generator... ...and observe the output.*" So presumably +ve from the function generator connects to "in", +ve from the power supply to "+5 volts", and scope probe to "out".

Having searched the web and studied various clamp schematics, I still can't work out the answer to my question which is, where to put the ground leads from function generator, power supply and oscilloscope?

Thanks

David

Comment: Ground is 0V,  **by definition**  It is assumed to be low impedance relative to any voltage source such as +5V

Comment: Simply connect all of your ground leads from the scope, function generator, and power supply together and your'e good to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would draw the schematic like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiS8TJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That (for me) makes it easy to see that the diode will start to conduct when the voltage at **out** exceeds 5 V + the diode's forward voltage, so at about 5.6 V.

Answer (score 2):

The schematic is missing a ground connection which would connect the ground of the power supply, function generator and oscilloscope probe together.

Comment: Thanks EE_socal. That makes sense, but just to check I understand properly: the scope probe ground is connected to mains supply earth; the power supply has a choice of mains supply earth or "COM" (not earthed); and the function generator ground is also not earthed. Having watched EEVblog #279 - How NOT To Blow Up Your Oscilloscope! <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaELqAo4kkQ> I think it's all right to connect these together but just wanted to check.

Answer (score 1):

In the place which´s written 5 Volts you should put the positive of your power supply. The negative terminal would be the ground, along with all other grounds coming from function generator and oscilloscope.

Answer (score 1):

That is only a partial schematic, the rest is implied and is shown below. The scope goes across the two terminals on the right.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjJO0d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>